# Update:modelValue - vue event name syntax

Tags: vue.js, web, events, syntax, vuejs3

I studied `v-model` construction syntax - [vue3 docs](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/migration/v-model.html). In this regard, I encountered the designation of an event through `update:modelValue`. Please provide a link to the `update:modelValue` notation syntax documentation. What does the first word (before `:`) and the second word (after `:`) mean?

I was looking for [vue event](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20vue&newwindow=1&sca_esv=559959589&sxsrf=AB5stBiQJx02zEvsM-Bt1ElzvA27So-qzw%3A1692945918443&source=hp&ei=_k3oZLT3GLq9xc8P-b6boAw&iflsig=AD69kcEAAAAAZOhcDrutg39xI6cZXuv6Oj-Yn9GHZPUx&ved=0ahUKEwi07tyAm_eAAxW6XvEDHXnfBsQQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20vue&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6IhfRgdC-0LHRi9GC0LjRjyDQstC-IHZ1ZTIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB5IqDVQAFiGLnAAeACQAQCYAY4GoAGWGaoBDjAuMTAuMS4xLjAuMS4xuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIHECMYigUYJ8ICBBAjGCfCAgsQABiABBixAxiDAcICBBAAGAPCAhEQLhiABBixAxiDARjHARjRA8ICBRAAGIAEwgILEC4YgAQYxwEYrwHCAhEQLhiABBixAxiDARjHARivAcICCxAuGIAEGLEDGIMBwgIIEC4YgAQYsQPCAggQABiABBixA8ICCBAuGLEDGIAEwgILEAAYigUYsQMYgwHCAgUQLhiABMICCxAAGIAEGLEDGMkDwgIIEAAYigUYkgPCAggQABiKBRixA8ICBxAAGA0YgATCAgYQABgeGA0&sclient=gws-wiz#ip=1), but found nothing suitable.

Comment: Hi, you can check these two section in docs.
[v-model-arguments](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#v-model-arguments)
[multi-v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#v-model-arguments)

Comment: @TanzerAtay The documentation pages, that you cited, do not explain the syntax of the `update:modelValue` expression - exactly `update:modelValue`. I need a documentation page specifically for the `update:modelValue` statement, it's syntax.